# Use mapbox GL or PNG depending on browser support

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

For a while in my ionic (v1) app I used to display a map using leaflet. But for performance reasons, I also used to create the map using this plugin for browsers that support WebGL.

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet

In this case I just had to check the browser compatibility and set the map to a normal PNG or a GL map.

With MapBox it doesn't seem to be that simple, as the methods for the two plugins are differents.

So I would like to know if there is a way to do it directly with mapbox. I searched for a while now and I still didn't find a way to accomplish that.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean "set the map to a normal png"? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Well, with Mapbox.js, you are able to display a map composed of "normal" image tile. And with MapboxGL, you display tiles that are vectorial. The problem is that not all device support vector tile. So i would like to switch between the two depending on browser support.

Comment: Are you asking about how to check for browser compatibility for WebGL? - The issue maybe that whatever you generate on one version (say Mapbox-gl) may not be fully supported in leaflet - so take care in that regard.

This [block](http://bl.ocks.org/danswick/c280d49d7dae91dc351a8f0d4da99af0) has a section on verifying if mapbox-gl is supported

Comment: Actually I am not looking for a way to check for browser compatibility. If we look at the two API (MapBox GL and MapBox.js) we see that the methods are not the same. For example adding a marker with MapBox GL is : `var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()`. Whereas for MapBox.js, it's `L.marker([50.5, 30.5])`. I was hoping there was a way so that ONLY the map declaration was different.

Does that mean I will have to check for browser support, every time I need to do something like adding a marker ?